# Script when passing values from one HTML page to other in Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

How to create Selenium IDE script when passing value [Using hyperlink] from one HTML page to other.

In my case the page was automatically closed After passing the value. When i am trying to run the test using Selenium IDE showing error like "[error] modifyWindow: Window was closed!"

The sample of the web page is like this

[image]

When i click on 'Search Customer ID' button of the first form, it will show a pop up window [like HTML Page 2]. After searching customer name, a list of details will shows in the pop up window. Select one of the customer by click on '**Select**'[hyperlink] and the customer ID details are automatically loading to the first page [In the Customer ID field of HTML page 1]. At this time the second window will closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, it sounds like you have a test that clicks on a hyperlink, that will then close the current window and open a new one?  If that is not correct, please add more details.

In order to instruct Selenium to use the new window, you need to use:

```
selectWindow(windowID)
```

The `windowID` would be the title of the window.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `selectWindow` command to set the focus on a different window, for example:

```
Command         Target               Value
------------------------------------------
waitForPopUp                         15000
selectWindow   title=Hello World
```